# Error while filtering a pyspark DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, filter, pyspark

I am attempting to filter my DataFrame to remove entries with counts less than 100. The DataFrame results from the "COMBINED" is below:

`Row(movieID=26, avg(rating)=3.452054794520548, count=73)`

When I run the code below, I get the following error:

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'int'

```
movieDataset = spark.createDataFrame(movies)
movieratings = movieDataset.groupBy("movieID").mean().drop("avg(movieID)")
topMovieIDs = movieDataset.groupBy("movieID").count()
combined = movieratings.join(topMovieIDs, on=["movieID"], how='inner')
filtered = combined.filter(combined.count >= 100).collect()
```

How can I filter the DataFrame by the count with 100 or greater?

Answer (score 0):

Disregard, got it to work.

should looke like

```
filtered = combined.filter(combined[2] >= 100).collect()
```

Comment: using `combined[2]`, you are not calling `count` directly, you're calling the 3rd column. What if the schema change? Add more columns or change the order, and your code does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```py
filtered = combined.filter(combined["count"] >= 100).collect()
```

`count` is by default a dataframe method name. Using `combined.count` is ambigouis and can refer to both the method or the column, so you have to be more specific.

---

This should work too :

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
filtered = combined.filter(col("count") >= 100).collect()
```